# Put XML in a DataGrid view inside WPF

Tags: xml, wpf, powershell, datagrid

I have a DataGrid inside my WPF application and I would like it to contain values from my XML file. The DataGrid is shown below:

```
<TabItem Header="Datacopy">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="GrdDatacopy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="320" Width="640">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Source}" Header="Bron:"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Destination}" Header="Doel:"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

My XML:

```
<DataCopy Dir="H:\O365-Source">
  <Row Source="C:\Temp" Destination="Temp" />
  <Row Source="C:\Downloads" Destination="Downloads" />
  <Row Source="C:\Muziek" Destination="Muziek" />
</DataCopy>
```

I can create a object for the datagrid

```
$DatacopySet = @{}
$XmlOffice365.Office365.Datacopy.Row | ForEach {
    $DatacopySet.add($_.Source))
    $DatacopySet.add($_.Destination))
}
$DatacopySet | ForEach-Object { .................... }
```

But when I paste in the  secion my whole app crashes, it should be something with the bindings.

How can I get my XML keys in the datagrid and be able to edit these.

I've found some samples but I couldn't get this to work...

PS1 script http://poshcode.org/2259

XAML code: http://poshcode.org/2260

[Article on a Microsoft forum](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2ee3aa5-f51d-44c9-a9d1-62621d0f783a/powershell-wpf-gui-looping-through-datagrid)

Hope that someone can help, or is there a other way to easaly edit and add values in this sort of setting?

Regards, Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display your xml data in the following way

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlDataCopy" XPath="DataCopy">
        <x:XData>
            <DataCopy xmlns="" Dir="H:\O365-Source">
                <Row Destination="Temp" Source="C:\Temp" />
                <Row Destination="Downloads" Source="C:\Downloads" />
                <Row Destination="Muziek" Source="C:\Muziek" />
            </DataCopy>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlDataCopy}, XPath='Row'}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath='@Destination'}" Header="Destination" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath='@Source'}" Header="Source" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Note:

-XmlDataProvider can be used with different Sources, including URIs

-Note the empty xmlns="" in the xml-snippet. You easily run into namespace issues otherwise.

-Editing the document is also possible in case the XmlDataProvider's Source is a variable in memory. You must call XmlDocument.Save() manually.

Hope this helps a bit, regards Snowball

Comment: Hi Snowball, thanks for your help. I've managed to get the data visible but I'm not able to generate the rows dynamicly to the WPF form. I'm still searching for a solution, but I now now how it works. Looks cool though :)